# How to insert an array into an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a problem with inserting arrays into an array. My code is like:

```
function routesL($location,$connexion){ //prend le id de quartier et récupere les quartiers disponibles pour deplacer

    $req = "SELECT idQArivee, transport
            FROM p1810512.Routes 
            WHERE idQDepart = '$location'";
    $res = mysqli_query($connexion,$req);
    $arr = array();
    $i=0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $new = array(
            'idQArivee'.$i = $row.'idQArivee',
            'transport'.$i = $row.'transport'
        );
        array_push($arr, $new);
        $i++;
    }
    if($arr == null){
        return null;
    }else
        return $arr;
    }
```

and the function *array_push()* is not working. **$row** is a table with two column *idQArivee* and *transport*. I am trying to take them and to insert into an array.

Comment: You can't concatenate `array` with `string` values here -> **$row.'idQArivee'**

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error appears to be a missing `;` after

```
$new = array(
        'idQArivee'.$i = $row.'idQArivee',
        'transport'.$i = $row.'transport'
    )
```

and the fact you cannot concatenate `$row.'idQArivee'` it should have been `$row['idQArivee']` and ditto with the `transport` occurance

So the fix is

```
$new = array(
        'idQArivee'.$i => $row['idQArivee'],
        'transport'.$i => $row['transport']
        );
$arr[] = $row;
```

Or simply

```
$arr[] = array(
        'idQArivee'.$i => $row['idQArivee'],
        'transport'.$i => $row['transport']
        );
```

> Additional Info
>
> To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
>   `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
>   This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: In fact the problem is in concatenation and `;`, she rewrites indexes during fetching and pushes values in wrong way, she doesn't needs `simplifying`

Comment: @AksenP Oh yes, you have a good point, although I would bet there is no need to do that :)

Comment: @AksenP Although we both missed the `=` which should be `=>` :)

Comment: yep, you're right, my eyes are sleepy now, time to bed)

Comment: @AksenP Night Night

Answer (score 1):

You seems to be missing the `>` and the trailing semicolon in the array statement 
e.g.

```
$new = array(
            'idQArivee'.$i => $row['idQArivee'],
            'transport'.$i => $row['transport']
        );
```

I'm not sure why you are assigning unique values to the keys for each array.

Depending on how you are going to use these, you might want to use...

```
$arr[] = array(
            'idQArivee' => $row['idQArivee'],
            'transport' => $row['transport']
        );
```

and drop the push as @RiggsFolly mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the output you want, this will append your increment (not a good way):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $arr['idQArivee'.$i] = $row['idQArivee'];
    $arr['transport'.$i] = $row['transport'];
    $i++;
}
```

But the standard (and better) way is to have a multi-dimensional array:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $arr[] = $row;
}
```

Or simply:

```
while($arr[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res));
```

If you use the [MySQL Native Driver](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php), then just:

```
$arr = mysqli_fetch_all($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

All of these will still give you `idQArivee` and `transport` keys since you specified them in the query and you are fetching associative.